# Создание ассоциативного массива из фала php

Tags: php, php7

Есть файл name.txt, где есть username и password разделенные табом, и данные начинаются с новой строки
username1  pass1
username2  pass2

Я пытаюсь прочесть файл через file_get_content, но возникла проблема, как мне пройтись по файлу циклом, и чтобы создать ассоциативный массив username -> passs

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем вы логин и пароль храните в файле

Comment: @Дмитрий не совсем понятно зачем это Вам должно быть понятно. Для ответа на вопрос этого не требуется, а демагогию разводите в другом месте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *пытаюсь прочесть файл через file_get_content*

Читайте файл функцией `file()`, она вернёт массив, который вы уже будете обрабатывать на наличие пары пароль-юзернейм:

```
$lines = file('name.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$array = [];

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    list($username, $password) = explode("\t", $line)
    $array[$username] = $password;
}

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Работает как по маслу.  Надо больше прочесть о функции file(). Я сам просто на js работаю, а сейчас попросили перезалить бд, и дали данные. Вот и мучился.

Answer (score 0):

```
$credentials = [];
$file_handle = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line = fgets($file_handle);
    $resArr = explode("\t", $line);
    $credentials[$resArr[0]] = $resArr[1];
}
fclose($file_handle);
```